# Problems with Telerik MVC Grid with CSS Framework EZ-CSS

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a page layed out with EZ-CSS. On this page I have a Telerik MVC Grid.  It works just fine except that column resizing and reordering is not working.  Also Ajax databinding does not work.  It always uses server binding.

The same grid worked perfectly on a page not layed out with EZ-CSS.  So it seems that EZ-CSS did something that is not compatible with the grid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have to apologize to the EZ-CSS guys.  I figured out that the problem was that I also changed to a newer jQuery version.  My fault - never do multiple changes at once.  Ok, here my findings:  Telerik's MVC Grid works with jQuery 1.5.1.  I upgraded to 1.6.2 and that is not compatible with the grid.  After going back to jQuery 1.5.1 all worked fine together with EZ-CSS.